# How to search on a public key

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

So i have the public keys in my data base and i want to search them using the sha256 hashed version (like the hashed version in git) so what i am doing is this

```
upper(encode(digest(btrim(key::bytea, ''::bytea), 'sha256'), 'base64')) LIKE upper(hashed_key)
```

but the result of this is not the same as it is in git

in python i am replication the process with

```
base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(binascii.a2b_base64(key)).digest()).rstrip(b'=').decode('utf-8')
```

and this is working but i need the postgresql version.If i remove the `binascii.a2b_base64(key)` part from the python code the outcome will be the same as the sql query but i want the sql query outcome to become like the python one.

Comment: What is the format of `key` in PostgreSQL?  If it is a base64-encoded value, then you need to pass it through `decode()` before hashing to match your python code.  Casting to `bytea` does not do this for you.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html

Comment: @MikeOrganek no it is just a text field as i understand it if i remove the ```binascii.a2b_base64(key)``` part from the python code and just give it the key their out put is the same but i am not sure about that so i did not say it in the question

Comment: i tested and ```binascii.a2b_base64(key)``` this part makes the difference

Comment: Does this work?  `encode(digest(decode(key, 'base64'), 'sha256'), 'base64')`

Comment: yes it does thank you so the problem is i should have decoded from base64 first  ?

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly it.  Your Python code does that as the innermost call is `a2b_base64()`.  So long as the value for `key` is the same in both Python and PostgreSQL, then you need to make that the first step in your PostgreSQL code, as well.  Without that step, your cast converts the base64 representation of your key into its bytes instead of the original key.